# Triggering object detection model using ultrasonic sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to start my object detection model when my ultrasonic sensor start detect the object in front of it at certain distance. what could be the possible function to make that happen.

I have tried to capture the picture and tried to make oop classifications which can be triggered in my main code.

Comment: More information is needed. Issue is not clear

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic].